# Implementing and resolving many service decorators in Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, decorator

I'm new to Castle Windsor, so I'm not sure what the best practise is in cases like the following:
I have a service interface (ILoader), that is implemented by multiple Loader classes. I also have an implementation of ILoader that's a decorator:

```
public interface ILoader { }
public class LoaderImpl0 : ILoader { }
public class LoaderImpl1 : ILoader { }
public class CachedLoader : ILoader
{
    public CachedLoader(ILoader inner) { }
}
```

For each LoaderImpl... class, I want to register a CachedLoader in my container, that decorates a LoaderImpl... instance.

Here's my first rubbish attempt:

```
container.Register
(
    Component.For<LoaderImpl0>().Named("loader0"),
    Component.For<LoaderImpl1>().Named("loader1"),
    Component
    .For<ILoader>( )
    .ImplementedBy<CachedLoader>( )
    .ServiceOverrides( ServiceOverride.ForKey( "inner" ).Eq( "loader0" ) )
    .Named("cachedLoader0"),
    Component
    .For<ILoader>()
    .ImplementedBy<CachedLoader>()
    .ServiceOverrides(ServiceOverride.ForKey("inner").Eq("loader1"))
    .Named("cachedLoader1")
);
```

This just seems wrong, on 2 counts:

- `container.ResolveAll<ILoader>()` returns all 4 registered loaders (even though I haven't registered the LoaderImpl... classes with the ILoader service).
- It seems like a very clumsy way to define what is a very common nested relationship - I don't really care about the LoaderImpl... classes, they should really be anonymous.

Can someone enlighten me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: How do you intend to use it? Do you always resolve all `ILoader`s at once? Or do you just want to have cached loader each time you request an `ILoader`?

Comment: Hi, yes I want to resolve all ILoaders at once - well, I think so. I want to inject an array of all of them into a loader manager. I think I have to do this manually, as using an array resolver is a bad idea? Also, not every ILoader implementation suits having a cached loader.

Comment: Perhaps using AOP would be better idea then? http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2007/03/11/AOP-With-Windsor-Adding-Caching-to-IRepositoryT-based-on-Ts.aspx

Comment: hmm interesting I'll give it a go. I should really refactor my question, though, because it comes in two parts. AOP would solve the caching of loaders (although it seems a bit of overkill - can't I inject an anonymous LoaderImpl class directly into a CachedLoader), and why does ResolveAll<ILoader> return all 4 loaders? Shouldn't it just return the 2 cached loaders?

Comment: That's just how ResolveAll works - it means "Give me all components that I can use as `ILoader` not just these that were registered as `ILoader`". Most of the time that's the preferred behavior.